# Cannot activate iTunes Connect account as a team

Tags: itunes, apple-id, app-store-connect, developer-program

I came across this question which is my exact issue:
[Do I have to enroll an Apple Developer Program to access itunes connect as a team member?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198398/do-i-have-to-enroll-an-apple-developer-program-to-access-itunes-connect-as-a-tea)

I am part of a team and have access to the developer part of apple. But I cannot activate my iTunes Connect invitation.

However, when i get the last step of the answer to "click the activation link" I am not asked to login, but rather enter a new password, and type a secret question.

When I enter this information and click "Save" it tells me "You need to sign in with your Apple ID to change your secret question."
What? I'm trying to activate my iTunes connect account so i can publish to the app store as part of the team, everything else is already setup...

Does anyone have a workaround or anything to get my activation link working?
I assumed it would just ask me to sign in, not change my password and secret question...

Surely I myself don't need a paid developer account to access the team I was added to.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear but you have to authenticate here first: https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin